# List - Index Out Of Range

Tags: python

I'm trying to get familiar with python, I've been converting some C# code over into python and I've ran into an error i can't figure out, i'm getting a "Index Out Of Range" error, this is my python code:

```
import random

myString = raw_input("Input: ")

words = myString.split(" ")
wordList = list()

for word in words:
    wordList.append(word) 

wordChoice = 0;
myStringRandomized = "";

while len(wordList) != 0:
    wordChoice = random.randint(0, len(wordList))
    myStringRandomized += wordList[wordChoice] + " "
    del wordList[wordChoice]

print("Characters: " + str(len(myString)))
print("Words: " + str(len(myString.split(" "))))
print("Uppercase: " + myString.upper())
print("Lowercase: " + myString.lower())
print("Randomized: " + myStringRandomized)
```

And the working equivalent in C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Input: ");
    string myString = Console.ReadLine();

    string[] words = myString.Split(' ');
    List<string> wordList = new List<string>();

    foreach (string word in words)
        wordList.Add(word);

    Random random = new Random();

    int wordChoice = 0;
    string myStringRandomized = "";

    while (wordList.Count != 0)
    {
        wordChoice = random.Next(0, wordList.Count);
        myStringRandomized += wordList[wordChoice] + " ";
        wordList.Remove(wordList[wordChoice]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Characters: " + myString.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Words: " + myString.Split(' ').Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Uppercase: " + myString.ToUpper());
    Console.WriteLine("Lowercase: " + myString.ToLower());
    Console.WriteLine("Randomized: " + myStringRandomized);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It would be great if someone could point out where I've gone wrong, thank you very much!

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's an answer, not a comment. Why miss out on sweet, sweet reputation points? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint), `random.randint` can *include* the value of `b` (in this case, `len(wordList)`). Instead, you should use [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange), which is half-open (like `range`) and *won't* include the `stop` value (and, as `0` is the default `start`, you can leave it out).

Comment: That's done it, thanks a lot for the quick answer! appreciate it :)